# Symfony 2 : services dependencies failed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.7

Since yesterday, I can't understand why i have this error on my Symfony website.
I have a service which depends on others. When i try to use and inject the Symfony doctrine entity manager i have errors. I can't find a way to do it :(

My config :

```
mycompany_jobs_bundle.processor.crm.product_matrix:
    class: %mycompany_jobs_bundle.processor.crm.product_matrix.class%
    parent: pim_base_connector.processor.product_to_flat_array
    arguments:
      - '@pim_catalog.repository.attribute'
      - '@pim_catalog.localization.factory.date'
      - '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
```

*(I also tried 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager' instead of '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager' -> same results)*

Then, in my service :

- I add a "**use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;**" with the other "use" lines.
- And this is my constructor :

[image]

... but i have this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 8 passed to
>   Mycompany\Bundle\JobsBundle\Processor\Mycompany\ProductWordMatrixProcessor::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Pim\Component\Catalog\Repository\AttributeRepositoryInterface,
>   instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given

Wherever i move my line "EntityManager $em" i have error with arguments position. What's wrong ? I can't understand ..

Thanks for your help

**Edit :** below the yml config of the parent service, pim_base_connector.processor.product_to_flat_array :

> ```
> pim_base_connector.processor.product_to_flat_array:
>    class: %pim_base_connector.processor.product_to_flat_array.class%
>    arguments:
>        - '@pim_serializer'
>        - '@pim_catalog.manager.channel'
>        - '@pim_catalog.builder.product'
>        - ['pim_catalog_file', 'pim_catalog_image']
>        - %pim_catalog.localization.decimal_separators%
>        - %pim_catalog.localization.date_formats%
>        - '@akeneo_storage_utils.doctrine.object_detacher'
> ```

Comment: can you post the definition of the parent service too?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the EntityManaer as the last parameter of your constructor arguments like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
   //.. others
   AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
   EntityManager $em
}
```

You need to maintain the order of your dependencies declared inside the configuration

Comment: I get the same error (yes, i cleared cache brefore to try)

Comment: @Paolito75 Once again, update your question with the actual code.  Your question (and error) indicates the em is being passed as the 8th argument but your class expects it to be in the 10th position.  And by the way, having 10 constructor arguments strongly suggests your class is doing too much.

Answer (score 0):

You constructor has 10 arguments and all of them should be configured. You specified only 7. You have to specify last 3 as well and check the order. It's important.